# CRM 2015: Archive options for Audit logs

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are using MS CRM 2015 and we are looking to know our options/best practice to archive audit logs. Any suggestion please? Thanks!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with software development. Please read the implementation guide, white papers etc. or try Microsoft Forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MSCRM Toolkit at http://mscrmtoolkit.codeplex.com/, which has a tool called Audit Export Manager to aid in archiving audit logs.  The documentation for the tool is available at http://mscrmtoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation#auditexportmanager .  The key items that this tool allows you to do is to do filtering by entities, Metadata, summary or detail, picking individual users, actions, and/or operations to include in your export.  Exports can be limited to a particular date range and can be exported to CSV, XML, or XML spreadsheet 2003 format.  Note that I've had trouble exporting with a couple of the formats, but typically get good results when exporting to CSV formats.

This is one of the tools I've found that gives you some flexibility when exporting audit records since Microsoft CRM allows you to filter the audit data, but doesn't provide a good built in means to export it.

Comment: Thank you @Chad ! I am aware of this option however we can end up having million of records and exporting to CSV or Excel could not be the best practice. What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using CRM Online or CRM On-Premise?  If using CRM On-Premise, then querying SQL could work or using some SSRS reports (although the way the filters are done is with bit-masks, so this may be the tricky part).  Ideally this is probably something to take that data and dump it into a SQL Server data warehouse as that would make querying easier and likely better for quickly understanding the data.  Is the end goal just to have it available if needed to look up old audit data?

Comment: Yes it's on Premise and our goal is to look up old audit data if needed :)

Comment: That should work well then to back up the data in the audit table and use it on a SQL Analysis server for historical analysis/querying purposes.  You could even use it with SQL Server as a straight table and if you enable full text indexing on this table, querying with the full text query syntax should allow for very fast queries.  The only thing I haven't found good documentation for is what the attribute mask values correspond to, but comparing some test audit records to what gets created in the audit table should allow you to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try newest [Stretch Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935011.aspx) feature from SQL Server 2016:

> Stretch Database migrates your cold data transparently and securely to the Microsoft Azure cloud.
>
> Stretch warm and cold transactional data dynamically from SQL Server to Microsoft Azure with SQL Server Stretch Database. Unlike typical cold data storage, your data is always online and available to query. You can provide longer data retention timelines without breaking the bank for large tables like Customer Order History.

There is a helpful hands-on review [SQL Server 2016 Stretch Database](http://blog.devart.com/sql-server-2016-stretch-database.html) with very interesting `SWITCH TABLE` example.

Also there must be a solution with moving archived data from audit to separate filegroup. Take a look to [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160):

> You can use the Transact-SQL `ALTER TABLE...SWITCH` statement to quickly and efficiently transfer subsets of your data in the following ways:
>
> - Assigning a table as a partition to an already existing partitioned table.
> - Switching a partition from one partitioned table to another.
> - Reassigning a partition to form a single table.